# How to modify react extended class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So let's say I have this

```
class ExampleOne extends ExampleTwo
```

and in ExampleTwo has this

```
return (
    <div className="test">
        <MyComponent exampleLabel="ExampleTwo">
```

Is it possible to modify MyComponent's exampleLabel to say "ExampleOne" for class ExampleOne?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two scenarios

1) If you can modify ExampleTwo, use react `props`

```
class ExampleTwo extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <div>
          <MyComponent exampleLabel={this.props.exampleLabel || 'ExampleTwo'}/>
        </div>;
      }
}
// And render as 
<ExampleOne exampleLabel="ExampleOne"/>
```

2) If you can't modify ExampleTwo, then you can override `render` function

```
class ExampleOne extends ExampleTwo {
   render() {
        return <div>
          <MyComponent exampleLabel="ExampleOne"/>
        </div>;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Extending ExampleOne is fine, you would just pass it as a prop like so:

In ExampleTwo:

```
return (
    <div className="test">
        <MyComponent exampleLabel="ExampleOne">
```